# Is it possible to complete the square on an expression where there is no third term?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example, in $x^2 - 8x$, if you are asked to 'complete' the square, how do you deduce the third term (C) ?

Comment: You could add and subtract the term, so in this case, you might write $x^2-8x=x^2-8x+16-16=(x-4)^2-16$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd term is: $\left(\dfrac{-8}{2}\right)^2 = 16$. In general, if you have:

$x^2 + ax$, then the 3rd term is: $\dfrac{a^2}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2-8x=(x^2-2\cdot x\cdot4+4^2)-4^2=(x-4)^2-4^2$$